# How to apply changes in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I know that JTable allows us double click on cells in order to edit the data. However, I don't know how to make the change affect on the array which was stored in JTable.
Please help me, thanks you.

Comment: When "committed", the editor will signal the `JTable`, which will take the value from the editor and pass it to the model's `setValueAt` method, which is your opportunity to update the internal state of the model, and fire of a `tableCellUpdated` event.

Comment: I'd recommend having a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) as a starting point

Comment: You need a `TableModelListener`, which will receive notification when data in your table gets modified by the user.  Check out [this section in the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

Comment: What is the result of `TableModel::isCellEditable`? Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get/create an instance of your table model

   ```
   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);
   ```
2. Set the value

   ```
   model.setValueAt(value, row, column);
   ```
3. Fire update event

   `model.fireTableCellUpdate(row, column);`